# Label update is null

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsoutlineview

I'm having an issue with a label not updating correctly in my UI. I have an Mac OS X app which uses a outline view to switch views. I want to simply have the date displayed to the user in a label on the view which is switched to (FirstViewController). When implemented alone in a new project I have no issue. But when implemented where the view changes, the value of the label does not update, in fact the console output indicates that _dateLabel is (null) even after being set prior. Any suggestions? I must be missing something quite fundamental!

Console output:

2014-08-30 19:54:22.719 OutlineView[10420:1613022] StringedText is 30 August 2014

2014-08-30 19:54:22.720 OutlineView[10420:1613022] label value is (null)

**I include the following code:**

```
//
//  FirstViewContorller.h
//  OutlineView


#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface FirstViewContorller : NSViewController

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *dateLabel;

-(void)updateDateScreen;

@end


//
//  FirstViewContorller.m
//  OutlineView


#import "FirstViewContorller.h"

@implementation FirstViewContorller
@synthesize dateLabel = _dateLabel;

-(void)updateDateScreen{
    //date calculation for main window
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
    NSString *stringedText = [formatter stringFromDate:now];
    _dateLabel.stringValue = stringedText;
    NSLog(@"StringedText is %@", stringedText);
    NSLog(@"label value is %@", _dateLabel.value);
}

@end




//
//  AppDelegate.m
//  OutlineView


#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "Book.h"
#import "FirstViewContorller.h"

@interface AppDelegate()

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSOutlineView *outlineView;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTreeController *booksController;

@end


@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    //other code here 

    //Call the update method in FirstViewController to load date label
    FirstViewContorller *instance = [[FirstViewContorller alloc]init];
    [instance updateDateScreen];

}

//further unrelated code

@end
```

Comment: You have to wait until viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear to update UI objects, since they don't exist until the view is loaded.  And you also need to make sure that the UI objects are properly linked to your class in the XIB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
NSLog(@"label value is %@", _dateLabel.value);
```

And because it is outputting "null" you think that your `value` is "null" when in all likelihood it is `_dateLabel` that is null.

You are creating the `instance` object, but then calling a method that updates a UI object, which may not have been unarchived from the xib file by the time you are calling it. So although your date formatter is correctly creating a string, it is trying to set it on a nil object.

You can see this for yourself by examining the output of of:

```
NSLog(@"label is %@", _dateLabel);
```

which will probably return a "null" as well.

Comment: Thanks Abizern - that makes a lot of sense what you are saying. So how do I go about updating the label from the method? I can't call it directly from the appDelegate, so I assume I can only call it from the class associated with the XIB?

Comment: The cell only appears after the view is loaded. So call it when the view loads or in `awakeFromNib`

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem. I simply moved my code to the awakeFromNib method and it now works fine. I thought I originally had the code there but that it wasn't being called - thus why I created the new method, but it is working now. Thank you so much for your help.